# how to format JSON by assigning values to node element in javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have JSON like below which has every element with field _value

```
"batchControlInfo" : {
  "sender" : {
    "_value" : "MMRPT"
  },
  "recipient" : {
    "_value" : "AAZTE"
  },
  "fileSequenceNumber" : {
    "_value" : 30
  },
  "fileCreationTimeStamp" : {
    "localTimeStamp" : {
      "_value" : 20200904052019
    },
    "utcTimeOffset" : {
      "_value" : "+0630"
    }
  }
}
```

How to Convert it to like below, just to remove _value which is in common to every node element.

```
"batchControlInfo" : {
      "sender" : "MMRPT",
      "recipient""AAZTE",
      "fileSequenceNumber" : 30,
      "fileCreationTimeStamp" : {
        "localTimeStamp" :  20200904052019,
        "utcTimeOffset" : "+0630"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done recursively as follows.

```js
const input = {
  "batchControlInfo" : {
    "sender" : {
      "_value" : "MMRPT"
    },
    "recipient" : {
      "_value" : "AAZTE"
    },
    "fileSequenceNumber" : {
      "_value" : 30
    },
    "fileCreationTimeStamp" : {
      "localTimeStamp" : {
        "_value" : 20200904052019
      },
      "utcTimeOffset" : {
        "_value" : "+0630"
      }
    }
  }
};

function getResult(input) {
  const output = {};
  for (const key in input) {
    if (input[key] && typeof input[key] === "object") {
      if ("_value" in input[key]) {
        output[key] = input[key]["_value"];
      } else {
        output[key] = getResult(input[key]);
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(getResult(input));
```

Comment: This will fail when there are objects with values of different type then `object` that are not named `_value`. Al tough it works for OP case.You might want to fix that for future readers. Adding `else { output[key] = input[key]; }` to your first `if` will fix that.